# Erro ao importar xml.parsers.expat em Python 2.7 so funciona com Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-2.7

Bom dia, ha uns meses comecei com python estou usando-o para fazer testes em aplicações android. Eu tenho o seguinte problema Importando o `xml.parsers.expat`.
quando executo direto no terminal ele funciona. Mais se eu executo usando `subprocess.call(import-expat.py, shell=True)` não funciona  e da um erro.

Esse é o script (import-expat.py):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import xml.parsers.expat
```

Esse é o erro:

```
 File "/opt/u_script_files/import-expat.py", line 2, in <module> import xml.parsers.expat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module> from pyexpat import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

Eu verifiquei as dependencias e no meu entender esta tudo certo:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd9b392000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1608877000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f16084b2000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f1608288000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1608ca6000)
```

Pensei que o arquivo libexpat.so.1 não existia e procureri ele

```
$ apt-file search libexpat.so.1
libexpat1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
libexpat1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
```

Mais ele existe sim, e está no path correto, então não sei onde esta o erro, 
pois executando direto no terminal funciona sim, mas usando o subprocess.call não funciona.

Dados adicionais:
S.O: Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Eu agradeço suas respostas.

**EDIT:**
Codigo onde é usado o subprocess.call:

```
user_path_script = '/opt/u_script_files/import-expat.py'
   for index, line in enumerate(listdevtotest):
     emulatorid = listdevtotest[index][0]
     subprocess.call(user_path_script + ' ' +  emulatorid, shell=True)
```

Eu fiz um teste local criei um script "call-import-expat.py"

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
subprocess.call('import-expat.py', shell=True)
```

e outro script "import-expat.py":

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import xml.parsers.expat
print "imported expat"
```

Se é executado no terminal: python call-import-expat.py, ele funciona bem e mostra o texto "imported expat".

Mas se o script é chamado via web(php) ele não funciona. Na web e chamado da seguinte forma:

```
$cmd = 'python /path/script/call-import-expat.py';
$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
pclose($proc);
```

**NEW EDIT:**

Acabei de editar essa linha

```
 $cmd = 'python /path/script/call-import-expat.py';
```

por esta:

```
 $cmd = 'python3 /path/script/call-import-expat.py';
```

Mudei python por python3. Mas o Python por default é 2.7. Não entendo porque funciona com Python3.

Comment: Posta a parte do código que chama o método `subprocess.call`.

Comment: @Dener Adicionei o código na pergunta. Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Izabel, você já tentou trocar o nome do seu arquivo?

As vezes o python 2.X reconhece como se fosse o mesmo arquivo da função!

Já a parte onde você diz que seu código roda normalmente com python 3 e não com o 2, pode ser por seu código Python ter sido escrito da forma que é padrão desta versão.

Caso queira testar, este código abaixo serve para você checar se seu código importa o módulo e caso ele não o faça, ele te responderá com um erro em sua tela!

```
try:
    import xml.parsers.expat
except:
    print(ImportError)
```